# How do I tell the waiter I want another drink: "Я повторяю это" or "Повторите это"?

Tags: выражения

When I finish my drink, I've often heard waitresses ask me: "Вы повторите это?" or something like that (maybe I heard wrong). The problem is I don't know how to ask for another drink. Do I say  "Я повторяю это" or "Повторите это пожалуйста"?

Comment: "Повторить" is too official and functional - as in it is OK when waiter says it, but coming from a guest would be difficult to make it sound polite. I'd stick to something like oldishly/jokingly asking for seconds "можно мне добавки?" or asking for another glass/cup/round "можно ещё стаканчик/чашечку/один/одну" - note -чк/чик suffix there to distinguish it from a tableware request. Also wouldn't hurt to mention exactly what you want: "Ещё один еспрессо, пожалуйста."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely waitresses asks not "Вы повторите это?" (Would you repeat it?) but "Вам повторить?" ("Would you like another?")
It would be OK to say "Повторите" or "Повторите пожалуйста".

Comment: Sometimes the waitress forgets to ask me if I want another, and I want to ask her. So would it make sense if I say: "мне повторить это, пожалуйста"  ?

Comment: It would be better to say "повторите, пожалуйста".

Answer (score 1):

"Я повторяю это" means "I repeat saying this"

"Повторите это пожалуйста" means "Please repeat what you just said"

"Вы повторите это?" means "Will you repeat what you just said?"

If the waiter hears the first one, he/she will think that you are getting angry about that they do not understand or hear you. If you say the next two, the waiter will repeat what they said before that.

If you want another portion of drink or food, you can say "Дайте ещё такое же"

Answer (score 0):

Option one would be awkward, if not rude.
The second is good when you ask her to repeat what she has just said.
Just say "Да, пожалуйста"

Comment: "Да, пожалуйста" means "Yes, please"